# Why can't I pass multiple array rows with $_POST?

Tags: php, arrays, forms, post, rows

I'm asking this again, better this time...

Using a form to pass an array via `$_POST`.  Data is a unique ID in a checkbox originally shown in an HTML table.  When I call the `$_POST['ids']` data, it will only call the first row.

Have called the data using various methods, always shows the first row, so it must be an error in my form.

```
<form style="float:right;" method='post' action='deldwg.php?folder=$folder' enctype='multipart/form-data'>

//…table setup

 if (mysqli_num_rows($results) >=1)
{
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results))
{
echo "<tbody><tr><td style='text-align:center;'><input type='checkbox'  name='ids[]' value='";
echo $row['id'];
echo "'></td>";
//…other columns, end form, etc...
```

Comment: how are you accessing the posted data?

Comment: I've tried all kinds of ways, always get first row.  Easiest way is: foreach ($_POST['ids'] as $key => $value) { $query="DELETE FROM table WHERE id='$value'" }

Comment: add `print_r($_POST['ids'])` does it contain what you expect

Comment: @tim:  always unique id of first checked box, not the others.

Comment: can you post the html, generated from the above, for the first 3 check-boxes

Comment: @tim:  Array ( [0] => 423 )

Comment: the actual html from the form `<input type='checkbox'  name='ids[]' ...`

Comment: @tim:  I'll be honest, I don't understand what you are asking.  They are checkboxes in an html table column.

Comment: the html generated by the code above is what i would like to see

Comment: What doctype are you using?

Comment: @user7314100 Can you please look at the html source page that, is the id are really unique? So I can help you further

Comment: Source for first two rows:  http://oi63.tinypic.com/2dqiq2x.jpg

Comment: @stuartp: html5

Comment: @user7314100 - ok that's fine - if xhtml I would have said to close the input tag. Not necessary for html5

Answer (score 0):

Ok,  the issue was that I ended my form tag before I ended my table tag in the HTML.  Thanks for everyone's help!